# JSON ValueError: Unterminated string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

My script work, but sometimes crashes with that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "planetafm.py", line 6, in <module>
    songs = json.loads(json_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 32 (char 31)
```

For example, that json causes:

```
rdsData({"now":{"id":"0052-55","title":"Summertime Sadness (Radio Mix)","artist":"Lana Del Rey","startDate":"2014-09-07 21:48:51","duration":"2014-09-07 21:48:51"}})
```

sourcecode:

```
import requests, json, re

url = "http://rds.eurozet.pl/reader/var/planeta.json"
response = requests.get(url)
json_data = re.match('rdsData\((.*?)\)', response.content).group(1)
songs = json.loads(json_data)
print (songs['now']['artist'] + " - " + songs['now']['title']).encode('utf-8')
```

Why that json is invalid? How to fix this?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regexp has a problem with closing bracket inside text. You can fix it by adding $ to the regexp:

```
import requests, json, re

url = "http://rds.eurozet.pl/reader/var/planeta.json"
response = requests.get(url)
print response.content
json_data = re.match('rdsData\((.*?)\)$', response.content).group(1)
print json_data
songs = json.loads(json_data)
print (songs['now']['artist'] + " - " + songs['now']['title']).encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method of extracting is flawed; your expression terminates at the first `)` character:

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://rds.eurozet.pl/reader/var/planeta.json"
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> re.match('rdsData\((.*?)\)', r.content).group(1)
'{"now":{"id":"0052-55","title":"Summertime Sadness (Radio Mix'
```

Rather than use a regular expression, just partition the value out using `str.partition()` and `str.rpartition()`:

```
url = "http://rds.eurozet.pl/reader/var/planeta.json"
response = requests.get(url)
json_data = response.content.partition('(')[-1].rpartition(')')[0]
songs = json.loads(json_data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> json_data = r.content.partition('(')[-1].rpartition(')')[0]
>>> json.loads(json_data)['now']
{u'duration': u'2014-09-07 21:48:51', u'startDate': u'2014-09-07 21:48:51', u'artist': u'Lana Del Rey', u'id': u'0052-55', u'title': u'Summertime Sadness (Radio Mix)'}
```